# One C# game to rule them all(iOS, Android, WP7, W7, Mac OS X and XBOX)

Tags: c#, android, windows, ios, windows-phone-7

Hey, I'm learning C# and just thought of a cool idea.  Considering that a game was simple enough.  Say, a remake of a classic text-entry style game, a C# game could theoretically be ported to all of the platforms I listed above, with little to no change of the original source code, correct?

Obviously the UI would have to be tweaked, and I highly doubt such a game would really survive on each of those platforms!

But, although C# is really MS heavy, through different methods, that could work, right?  Or, would I have to change the C# source to Objective-C?  Does Android even have an official language that they support like Apple and MS do?

This is kind of an odd question, but if this is true, then C# is really a nice all-purpose language even though it's largely based on and endorsed by MS.

Comment: Mostly it is a pipedream, you could use C#/XNA to make an Windows/Xbox/WP7 game and likely use C# via Mono/MonoTouch to make a OS X/iOS implementation.  Android doesn't have a suitable mono implementation at the moment to support this though. This is not at all meant to be discouraging, also MS has given the C# language to the community.. http://www.microsoft.com/interop/cp/default.mspx

Comment: You could submit this as an answer, but yeah, I've been looking into it and I would have though otherwise about Android.

Comment: Wouldn't it be iOS to cover the iPod touch and iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I decided to post an answer cause I thought of a few more relevant things to say.

First to answer your questions: Yes it would work. No, you wouldn't have to port to Objective-C. Android's apps often use Java.

And a bit more background...

I'm hearing good things about [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) and [MonoDroid](http://www.go-mono.com/monodroid/) for cross platform development using .Net, C#.

You've already accepted that you'll have to handle UI layers specifically for each platform, so you're on the right path.

Importantly, on Sept 9, Apple relaxed their guidelines that previously prevented apps built using Monotouch from being released in the marketplace.

[Statement by Apple on App Store Review Guidelines](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/09/09statement.html)

> *In particular, we are relaxing all restrictions on the development tools
>   used to create iOS apps, as long as
>   the resulting apps do not download any
>   code. This should give developers the
>   flexibility they want, while
>   preserving the security we need.*

Also of interest, from Craig Dunn's blog...

[ConceptDev (Craig Dunn's blog): MonoTouch meet WindowsPhone7](http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2010/09/monotouch-meet-windowsphone7.html)

Comment: Yes!  I knew there was a statement Apple made.  I need to find other apps built using monotouch and see if there is always lag..

Comment: You'll be right policy-wise on the Android side. The unique aspect of Android is that developers can do just about what ever we want, good or bad.

Answer (score 6):

Mostly it is a pipedream, you could use C#/XNA to make an Windows/Xbox/WP7 game and likely use C# via Mono/MonoTouch to make a OS X/iOS implementation. Android doesn't have a suitable mono implementation at the moment to support this though.

This is not at all meant to be discouraging, also MS has given the C# language to the community so that is positive..

http://www.microsoft.com/interop/cp/default.mspx

Answer (score 4):

I am not a game development expert, but here my 2 cents,

You dont have any problems with developing games in c# targets all the platforms, [mono c#](http://www.mono-project.com/) runs sucessfully in all above said plaforms including [monodroid](http://www.go-mono.com/monodroid/) - andriod and [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) - iphone.

But the problem is specific to the graphic libraries you are going to use. For example Xbox libraries only targets windows. But if you stick with openGL, you may solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the Mono links and the OpenGL suggestion!

Comment: I would have said the same as Ramesh in the context of your question. Via monotouch and monodroid you have the option to do C# on all platforms that you mentioned. You acknowledged you'd have to deal with the ui layer seperately, so that is a given.

Comment: Yeah, upon downloading a sample application made with monotouch however, you can almost instantly distinguish one built with monotouch from a standard objective-c app.. Sadly

Comment: I was talking to Craig Dunn about this a month or so ago.. if I haven't misunderstood, I believe  you can still use Cocoa for the UI. Adding a related link to my post while I'm looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off sticking to C++, for which iOS and Android have native support.

Comment: OK, although, I need to learn the basics of C# for ASP.NET sake, so I figured it would be nice to be able to write some games with the same language.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to *need* C#, after all you can use Vb.net for ASP.net development :) (no joking, its a better language especially considering the embedded xml support VB has)

However, for mobile development, I think you're going the wrong route for cross-platform development. For this, you're always going to get 80% of the coverage, that last 20% is going to be a pain. For example, if you choose C#, you'll get Windows and XBox, but not Playstation and very poor iPhone.

So, you need the lowest common demoninator - and that's probably C++. You can put a Qt GUI on top (with the excellent QML which is possibly the best UI tech at the moment), and that'll run on most platforms - including Android. But not WinPhone7. C++ is still a good option for all platforms as even Windows will run it (C++/CLI) and there's easy bridge between objective-C and C++ anyway. Your best option is probably to go that route (and a *lot* of games development is done in C++ anyway so its not wasted effort).

Chances are though, you're not ever going to get a single codebase to work well enough on all platforms. Perhaps javascript would be the ultimate though, as MS' [Bob Muglia has said](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsofts-muglia-reconfirms-html-is-microsofts-cross-platform-play/7854) they're not focussing on Silverlight anymore, preferring HTML5+javascript for cross platform work.

Comment: Well, you can use VB.net but there is so much more support for C#, and like I said, I could at least develop a strong forebear for XBOX, Windows and WP7.  I appreciate your answer but don't totally agree with you.  Of course there are better options, but it could work.

Comment: Worth looking at the html5+javascript story... even if it's just for the UI layer, it could even be the solution to making the ui layer cross platform, but it's still a plan for the future. You still have choice of what to use to implement whatever is under the hood (and on your server if applicable).

Comment: Regarding confusion surrounding Silverlight and BobMu at present, SteveB's statement also worth looking at. http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2010/nov10/11-01Statement.mspx The community interpretation seems a bit murky at the moment, may take a little time for the picture to become clear.

Comment: ps - I don't think the OP said he needed C#. Want, yes. He did also make clear which platforms he wants to target however and seems clear in his intention to seek an answer to that question.