# Android and Phone 7 porting?

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-7, porting

I am interesting in: what is the best way to write applications (for example games or business apps) for so different platforms like Android and Phone 7 with minimal changes in source code, logic and other developing artefacts? Or it is impossible and i must write my application two times from the "ground" for each of devices? Please tell me about your experience?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Voting to close. I think this is covered really well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066877/one-c-game-to-rule-them-allios-android-wp7-w7-mac-os-x-and-xbox/4066955#4066955

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to write your app twice in this case. I wouldn't recommend using mono for performance reasons. I also found it quite unreliable, tho it may work just ok for your apps.

Answer (score 2):

If it's possible for your app, create it as a web application, perhaps using some mobile web app framework.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 requires you to develop in C#. However, you can use Mono on both iPhone and Android. This allows you to reuse your business logic. Have a look at [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net/) and [MonoDroid](http://monodroid.net/). The MMI (Man-Machine Interface) needs to be done differently on each platform.

Good luck!